# React-Table aggregate rows

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using ReactTable and I am currently looking on how to aggragate rows.

Here is the data that I want to make a table of

```
[{GroupTitle: "Group Title 1",
  ArrayItem: 
          [{SubTitle: "Sub1", ID: 1},
           {SubTitle: "Sub2", ID: 1}]
  },
  {GroupTitle: "Group Title 2",
  ArrayItem: 
          [{SubTitle: "Sub3", ID: 3},
           {SubTitle: "Sub4", ID: 4}]
  }

]
```

I got the following code

```
<ReactTable
   columns={[
     {
      Header: "Parent",
      accessor: "GroupTitle",
      minWidth: 240,
      }
   ]}
SubComponent={row => {
   return (
    <ReactTable
        data={row.original.ArrayItem}
        columns={[
        { Header: "ID", accessor: "ID", id: "ID" },
         {
         Header: "Title",
          accessor: "Title",
           minWidth: 240
         }
          ]}

              />
            );
          }}>
```

I am not sure if subcomponents is the way to go if I want to aggragate my data using the "GroupTitle" because currently the documentation for subcomponents is not that useful. When I deploy this one it works but somhow it got extra blank rows to the sub components which I am not sure why.

If you could point out any good example that use subcomponents or let me know how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

Oops I think I know now why I got empty rows, I forgot to add minRows={0} property